# Oracle query with minus operator issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

Im trying to extract certain users in my database by comparing two tables. My query is this:

```
select 'alter user '||username||' identified by "kRobGc3$vs0cmzX";'
from dba_users
where default_tablespace='APPS_TS_TX_DATA'
and username not in ('John','Stacey','Mark','Jim')
minus 
select oracle_username from FND_ORACLE_USERID;
```

So when i execute above query it returns users that are filtered by my first select, and somehow bypass minus second select.

Any idea how to manage this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a subquery.

```
select 'alter user '||username||' identified by "kRobGc3$vs0cmzX";'
from (select username
        from dba_users
        where default_tablespace = 'APPS_TS_TX_DATA'
          and username not in ('John', 'Stacey', 'Mark', 'Jim')
      minus 
      select oracle_username 
        from FND_ORACLE_USERID
     );
```